# Want to fetch file name from folder and make hyperlink with the same files

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fetch all files name from a folder and create hyperlink with the same files.

Below mentioned is my code please assist.

```
Sub FileName1()
Dim I As Integer
Dim fl As File
Dim fldr As Folder
Dim SH As Worksheet
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim Fpath As String
Dim mpath As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Show
Fpath = .SelectedItems(1)
mpath = Fpath & "\"
End With

I = 1
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(Fpath)

For Each fl In fldr.Files
First.Cells(I, 1) = fl.Name
If First.Cells(I, 1) = fl.Name Then
First.Cells(I, 1).Select

First.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=First.Cells(I, 1), Address:=mpath,  TextToDisplay:=First.Cells(I, 1)

End If
I = I + 1
Next fl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
First.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=First.Cells(I, 1), Address:=mpath,  TextToDisplay:=First.Cells(I, 1)
```

To

```
First.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=First.Cells(I, 1), Address:=mpath & fl.Name,  TextToDisplay:=First.Cells(I, 1).Value
```